# Ultimaker 3 printing area?

Tags: ultimaker-3

I have designed a model with the dimensions 215x125x12 mm. According to my printer settings, the printing area of the Ultimaker 3 is 233x215x200 mm. But I can not get the model to fit. Why is that?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Ultimaker image 00]

[image: Ultimaker image 01]

Answer (score 5):

Yes that happens! It finds its source in various possible reasons.

- The print bed is not square! There are cutouts caused by the print head;
- The Ultimaker 3 has 2 nozzles, when you have 2 active, the effective print bed is smaller than with 1 nozzle active;
- Using a brim or a skirt also makes the effective print area smaller.

In re-creating your example, the settings in your projects are not correct (but even if done properly, you will not be able to print it flat on the bed). Take a look at the image below, as can be seen your example still has a brim/skirt reservation, be sure to disable the second extruder (as shown by a cross X before "Generic PLA" at the top).

[image]

The only solution to print this on this machine is to print it upright:

[image]

Comment: Brim and skirt are disabled, only nozzle 1 is active, the other slot is empty. Is 215 mm too big?

Comment: @F_Schmidt Are you sure, your image clearly differs from added images in the answer. E.g. have you disabled the second extruder.

Comment: I created the image before turning off. After that I was able to fit a model with width 207mm